# Odoo12: Setup SMPT Server with Sendinblue in Odoo. What I missed here?

Tags: smtp, odoo, sendinblue

I am trying to setup Sendinblue and use it as an SMTP server for my marketing and general Odoo 12 email messaging.

I setup every thing in Sendinblue and tested the SMTP Server in Odoo and got a "sucess" message under Settings / Technical / Outgoing Mail Servers.

For this I setup an external smpt server with the following data:

```
SMTP Server: smtp-relay.sendinblue.com
Email: my sendinblue email 
Password: Password provided by sendinblue
Port: 587
Security: TLS (STARTTLS)
```

I can test the connection with success and set this SMTP Server as the server for sending email campaigns from Email Marketing / Settings / General Settings

Created a test email campaign and tried to send it and test it with no luck.

When Odoo tries to send the message, returns a "not delivered email" message with a unique reference and my local PC name, something like:

989345297097442.1625436965.401543280300903-openerp-reply_to@MYPC-NAME

I confirm sender email is registered and validated in Sendinblue. Using the same email as sender in Odoo.

Tried to do the same with my personal gmail account but even activating less secure apps, no message is sent from my instance.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I had to verify the domain name I use for sending emails from Sendinblue service.
I have done it Senders & API main menu option on "domain" tab.
After verifying my domain name, everything is running fine